# C# Data Access GetAll() methods with many parameters

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, repository, data-access-layer

It's common to have methods like one below in the data access layer:

```
    Tuple<int, IList<Media>> GetAllWithFilter(int? page, string folderName, string title, string fileName, string author, string keywordTitle, int type, int fileType, int rowsPerPage, Guid keywordId, string sortField = null, string sortDir = null);
```

And it get's messier and messier every time a new property is added

What are the good practices to keep these methods readable and maintainable?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create an object that houses all your filter properties and just pass that around?

Answer (score 2):

I think this one would help. [Query pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html)